# C# A reference type variable that should be mocked by test classes but should not be visible outside of the class that defines it

Tags: c#, .net

*I am a beginner with C#*

In my class, there is a variable ( `Dictionary<string, string>` ) which is an implementation detail. It should not be visible outside of that class.

My first choice was to keep it `private`:

```cs
class MyClass 
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dict = new();
}
```

The Unit test of this project is in a different project, so if I want to access the variable to mock it, it would not be possible.

Thus, I had to make the variable `internal` and use `InternalsVisibleTo()`

```cs
class MyClass 
{
    internal Dictionary<string, string> dict = new();
}
```

Now, I can mock the variable in the test class, but with this change, `dict` is visible to the current assembly as well. So the classes which use the MyClass instance can do this:

```cs
MyClass myClass = new();
myClass.dict = new();
```

I can prevent it by making the variable an auto property and setting the set:

```cs
class MyClass 
{
    internal Dictionary<string, string> dict {get; private set;} = new();
}
```

With that, other classes would not be able to reassign the same variable, but they would still be able to update the dict:

```cs
MyClass myClass = new();
myClass.dict["key"] = "value";
```

How do I prevent this?

What I am looking for is A reference type variable that should be mocked by test classes but should not be visible outside of the class that defines it.

Comment: What are you trying to test here? I see a lot of people massively over-using mocks... perhaps the best solution here isn't to go through hoops to use a mock, but to avoid mocking in the first place. Without more information about what your class actually does, it's going to be hard to help though. (I'd suggest that normally mocking, or even test doubles in general, should normally be about *dependencies* - which can be passed into a constructor, usually.)

Comment: Could you initialize the Dictionary in the constructor method of `MyClass`?

Comment: @JonSkeet The dict is a cache. For the given key, it would fetch the value (which is also a string) from the API and save it. I don't have a lot of problems with mocking when it comes to testing `MyClass`. It becomes pain when an instance of `MyClass` is injected in some other class which needs to have the values from the `dict` available. `MyClass` actually has a lot of other such variables.

Comment: @AnandUndavia: Then perhaps you should be injecting an interface that `MyClass` implements instead (which you may need to create) - so you could fake or mock that instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can have your dictionary private, but you can create another public property which will provide read-only access. this way you see can mock it.

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Dict
    {
        get { return dict; }
    }
}
```

another way you can have a public method exposed which will allow access the dictionary in a very limited way

Comment: Helpful, But I would want to actually update the dict from test classes. And in the actual project, there are more reference type variables than just one. So it becomes a bit of overhead to have this for every variable. Isn't there a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

How about a method, that returns value from dict by key?
As bonus - check that key exists

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> dict = new();
    public string DictByKey(string key) => dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : null;
}
```

Comment: This does not help. I only want to modify the dict from inside of the class and test classes. It should not be modified from other classes within the same assembly. It should not even be visible to other classes because it is an implementation detail.